# Rails ORM for CouchDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, couchdb

MongoDB has two popular ORMs for Rails: MongoID and MongoMapper.

Are there CouchDB ORM:s for Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure since I've never used it, but it looks like CouchRest would be the way to go - specifically "[CouchRest Model](http://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model)" looks like has been updated to work with Rails3 ActiveModel.

FWIW, I landed on CouchRest after finding [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/couchrest/browse_thread/thread/965163eb628f1aaa/a216972c949444d9?lnk=raot).

Answer (score 1):

there is couchRest as noted above, or if you like active record style try [couch_foo](http://github.com/georgepalmer/couch_foo). I had different needs when i was looking into couch this past spring, and using rails 3.  Rails 3 should be ORM agnostic, so it shouldn't really mess with it, although I couldn't get testing to work easily, but that could have just been me.